# Xcode 12: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

I have a flutter application that I am trying to generate release for IOS out of it, but I am facing this error:

```
 sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
    rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

I have tried most of the internet solutions for this error and still get it the same, I am not sure if it is related to something specific or it is a general error, any suggestion would be highly appreciated

```
flutter build ios --verbose
```

here is the log:

```
/Users/husseinajam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-blmaktiwmbrumnfrwrxbcbrwqoqk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-
                            iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh
                        ♦ mkdir -p -- /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
                        ♦ rsync -av --delete /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/ios/../ios/Flutter/App.framework
                        /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks
                        building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/ios/../ios/Flutter/App.framework"
failed: No such file
                        or directory (2)
                        done
                    
                        sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
                        total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
                        rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at
                        /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
                        Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
                    
                        GenerateDSYMFile /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM
                        /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner (in target 'Runner' from project
'Runner')
                            cd /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/ios
                            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
                            /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner -o
                            /Users/husseinajam/Desktop/imim/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app.dSYM
                    
                    
[+8613 ms] "flutter ios" took 118,982ms.
[   +5 ms] Encountered error while building for device.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      BuildIOSCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:116:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #14     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #15     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
           
           
[ +744 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 257ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: You can try `flutter build ios --verbose`, and share the log with us.

Comment: I get the same error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". The app works fine in Android and on ios simulator, but Xcode12 cannot build and install on a physical iPhone. I also tried to downgrade to Xcode 11.4. It's an update to an app that is already on the App Store. It's very frustrating!! The error message I'm getting is: /Users/macmini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fchwywzctlcczngvfhcxqrylsnly/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Did anyone find the answer??I didn't get it work..

Answer (score -1):

have you tried the following;

- 'flutter clean' command -> run build(if supporting iOS 9 try changing it to iOS 11 for a test)
- Updating flutter to the latest version and running and running the first step?

Answer (score -1):

I am using Xcode 12.4

```
Build Settings -> Targets -> Build Active Architecture Only, set it to Yes.[Debug,Profile & Release for all]
```

Comment: I am still running in this error, any other fix?